# Application Insights "Error retrieving data"

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I'm dealing with a mysterious "Error retrieving data" on "Health" and "Application Map" widgets on the Application Insights as per today morning. I've checked the application insight status page, nothing unusual for today. I'm starting to suspect I did something wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This really seems like an Azure support question, regarding a potential transient portal issue. Doesn't fit on StackOverflow though - not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, its MS fault again. I checked the status and they've mentioned a problem exists then again it was solved.

Comment: still up to date in 2022 :D

Answer (score 2):

Bring up the dev tools panel and view network traffic.  Watch traffic when the tile is trying to update (maybe refresh page?) and look for some errors.  At my company the Zscaler firewall was blocking traffic to *.applicationinsights.io URL which is what the tiles were requesting data from, resulting in 403 errors.

Comment: For me it was an ad blocker that was preventing the data being retrieved. And here's an MS page that hints at the same thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/troubleshoot-portal-connectivity

Answer (score 1):

For others hitting this question, it's worth mentioning that I was getting this error in Application Insights due to an ad blocker preventing access to the app insights API. Turning off the blocker for the portal.azure.com domain got things working again.